# Convergence of of Series, |an| less than or equal to K*bn

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be sequences of real numbers 
such that $b_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

Assume that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}<\infty.$$ 
Show that there exists $K>0$ such that $|a_n|\leq K b_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

I have shown this by the fact $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ converges to $0$, as the series converges, and therefore, by the definition of convergence, for all (and hence there exists) $K > 0$, there exists $m \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n \geq m$ one has $|\frac{a_n}{b_n}| \leq K$.

Since $|\frac{a_n}{b_n}| = \frac{|a_n|}{|b_n|}$ it follows $|a_n| \leq K |b_n|$.
Because of $b_n > 0$ for all $n$ we have $|b_n| = b_n$ and therefore $|an| \leq K b_n$, and so it is proven.

Could someone point out any potential flaws in this, and if so, provide a correct proof? This is because while I feel my logic is sound, the proof given to me is different, and too complicated for me to understand, not to mention write down.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Hope I didn't change the meaning too much with my edit. For next time, use @Shaun link and try to write in LaTeX :)

Comment: Is $K$ supposed to work for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is nearly correct. The fourth paragraph isn't quite right. You could fix it by saying "since $\dfrac{a_n}{b_n} \to 0$, there exists a number $K > 0$ with the property that $\left| \dfrac{a_n}{b_n} \right| \le K$ for all $n$, because convergent sequences are bounded."

From that point on it looks fine.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I wrote that 'for all K' implies 'there exists K'. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: No. It is not true for all $K$. For any $K$, regardless of how small, there is some point $m$ in the sequence for which $|a_n| \le K b_n$ for all $n \ge m$. If you want the inequality for all $n$, you can't choose $K$ arbitrarily small.